# Properly dereferencing 2D dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, pointers

Suppose I have a custom class `MyClass`and it has the method `foo`

Now suppose I create a 2D dynamic array that is 10x10 of `MyClass` objects as follows:

```
    MyClass** 2Darr

    2Darr = new MyClass*[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        2Darr[i] = new MyClass[10];
    }
```

Would this be the correct way to dereference a `MyClass` object of this 2D array and call its' foo method:

```
    2Darr[5][5].foo()
```

Comment: Yes, but if you're having the same column count in each row a simple 1D array (better a vector) might be better suited.

Comment: I doubt if u can create a variable name with the first letter as a digit, though the way to dereference it is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Answer was given by others in comments to original question.